# How to search for a set of words in a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, text

I'm writing a project on extracting a semantic orientation from a review stored in a text file.
I have a 400*2 array, each row contains a word and it's weight. I want to check which of these words is in the text file, and calculate the weight of the whole content.

My question is -

what is the most efficient way to do it? Should I search for each word separately, for example with a for loop? 
Do I get any benefit from storing the content of the text file in a string object?

Comment: Your question is vague. Please read [ask] and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Do you want to know if any of the array-words exists at least once? Or do you want a count for each of the words in the array?

Comment: I use a 400x2 array. Each row caontains a word in the first cell, and a weight in the second cell. 
I want to search for these words in the text file and calculate it's content weight.

Comment: @Vic, please update your question with that comment, provide the input you have and output you want

Comment: I did so, thanks :)

Comment: How likely is it, that your 400 words change? Building a regular expression with 400 alternatives and a frame of word boundary criteria is surely worth a try, but I would build the pattern dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html

This may work for you. You can use find

Comment: bur for this I'll need a separate iteratiton for each word in the array, don't I?

Comment: I think you can use regex instead of separate iteratiton for each word

Answer (score 0):

This may be out of the box thinking, but if you don't care for semantic/grammatic connection of the words:

- sort all words from the text by length
- sort your array by length

.

- Write a for-loop:
- Call `len()` (length) on each word from the text.
- Then only check against those words which have the same length.

With some tinkering it might give you a good performance boost instead of the "naive" search.

Also look into search algorithms if you want to achieve an additional boost (concerning finding the first word (of the 400) with e.g. 6 letters - then go "down" the list until the first word with 5 letters comes up, then stop.

Alternatively you could also build an index array with the indexes of the first and last of all 5-letter words (analog for the rest), assuming your words dont change.

Comment: That's a really good idea, but my mistake was that I didn't mention that some of the cells contain expressions, like "well acted", and not just a single word.